# CS0102 The type 'A' already contains a definition for 'set_color'

Tags: c#, .net

I just came across the above error while I was trying to compile a proxy class generated through svcutil. Here's a short version of the problem:

```
class A
{
    private string colorField;
    private string set_colorField; 

    public string color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.colorField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.colorField = value;
        }
    }

    public string set_color
    {
        get
        {
            return this.set_colorField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.set_colorField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles fine:

```
public string Color
{
    get;set;
}

public string Set_Color
{
    get;set;
}
```

But this throws the same error:

```
public string color
{
    get;set;
}

public string set_color
{
    get;set;
}
```

I don't recall ever reading about this restriction. Can someone point me to the relevant section of the C# compiler spec?

Comment: @Kirk I understand that, but where's the relevant piece in the c# compiler spec mentioning this restriction? I couldn't find it :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#properties

> **Member names reserved for properties**
>
> For a property P (Properties) of type T, the following signatures are
>   reserved:

```
T get_P();
void set_P(T value);
```

In the case where you have `color` property, `set_color(...)` is reserved and that's why you can't have `set_color` property too, since it tries to compile to the same signature.

In the case where you have `Color` property, `set_Color(...)` is reserved for it and that's why `Set_Color` (note the Capital letter) works.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this as the answer as soon as I can - have to wait 10 minutes. I couldn't find it in all my Google searches.

Comment: This is why it's recommended to start Properties with Capital Letters.